# Why does my rails not run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run `$ rails -server` to start a server, there comes an error:

> Could not find gem 'sqlite3' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.

Does that mean I did not install `sqlite3`? How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to install all Gems from your `Gemfile`.

This can be done with `bundle install` or in short `bundle`.

If this command executed successfully, you can run your server with `rails s`.

But I think it's better for you, to start with a [tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

Answer (score 0):

`server` and `s` are not a switch, but a sub-command.

Run

```
$ rails server
```

or

```
$ rails s
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into this issue previously， that is because you run bundle install, miss some gems, so you can `$ bundle install` again,

and you can test the sqlite if is installed:

```
$ sqlite3 --version
```

If successed, you can test the `rails server`.